Kubuntu 24.10 "add virtual device" in audio settings not showing
Hi I'm trying to get simultaneous audio output in line out and headphones, I enabled "Show virtual devices" in volume control, but nothing happens, and the option to "Add virtual devices" in Audio settings in System settings, not showing. Thanks
Show Virtual Devices
Audio Settings

Same here. Kubuntu 24.04, plasmashell 5.27.11, kernel 6.8 (no idea if relevant)
